# Spring Transactions failing in multiple instance applications

Tags: oracle, spring-transactions, multiple-instances

Spring transactions in multiple instance application is failing regularly. Unable to reproduce. Failing with PK constraint(jobname+key)
Note: I have modified the query part to look-alike

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
    public boolean insertLockIfDoesNotExist(String jobName, String key) {
    
        try {   
            int affectedRowsCount = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
                    "insert into LOCK_SCH (JOB_NAME, KEY) select ?, ?  where not exists (select 1 from LOCK_SCH where JOB_NAME=? and EXECUTION_KEY=?) ")
                    .setParameter("jobName", jobName)
                    .setParameter("key", key)                    
                    .setFlushMode(FlushModeType.AUTO)
                    .executeUpdate();
            return affectedRowsCount > 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {            
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: using oracle          ....

Comment: Mixing a query by positional parameters (?) with setters of parameters by name (setParameter("jobName", jobName)) is not a good idea.

Comment: This probably answer your question https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=insert-if-not-exists.
Actually since you already have unique constraint, that isn't really a problem

Comment: How/where is the primary key generated? Sounds like your business logic (i.e. your code) needs to change to account for multiple app instances.